# ipfs.infura.io for IPFS gateway and pinning

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, ipfs

I'm using Infura API for initializing IPFS. IPFS uses garbage collector to clean 2 weeks old unpinned data in public gateway. So, if I'll pin my hash is it possible that IPFS will still delete my information from server because I'm using public gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc [https://docs.ipfs.io/] mentioned that **pinning** an item is essentially marking it for the garbage collector not to delete it, so it will not be deleted.

> if i will pin my hash is is possible that still IPFS deletes my
>   information from server because i am using public gateway

If using public gateway, more likely it will be deleted. This is similar to how BitTorrent works, there needs to be at least one seed for data to be available to the network. Just like with **pins**, every node decides what content is fetched and seeded (co-hosted). Since you are on Public gateway, it is most likely to be **deleted**.

Comment: Thanks for replying, So even if i pin my hash just because i am using public gateway it will be deleted!  So i need to run ipfs daemon in stand alone server and use it's address to initialize ipfs and pin it to keep in forever?

Comment: think it like in term of space for clarity and simplicity: if you are using public space it will be see as public and any overhead will be wiped out. but if you are using it in stand alone space of yours it will be marked to be freed but it just depends on your whims. Marked for garbage is not stuffs thrown away from your space.

Comment: Well, so, it means private node and pinned data is not full proof way to keep data in ipfs forever? then what should i do to make sure data stays intact ?

Comment: **Q:how can i ensure data remains online forever?**
you can do this by keeping one or several ipfs nodes online pinning the content you're interested in backing up,the more ipfs nodes pinning content,the better redundancy you get.Tools such as ipfs-persistence-consortium, pincoop,and ipfs-cluster on top of ipfs allow you to share the costs of bandwidth with other people or organizations.Then, protocols like Filecoin will allow you to just pay the network to do it for you (i.e. similar to how people pay "the cloud companies", but here you're paying the network itself).